# How make the font of price excl tax the same a incl tax

Tags: magento2, price, magento2.2.3

I want that price excl tax displays the same as incl tax. I can not find it. Magento 2.2.3

In which CSS file can I change that? The file for standard Magento 2.2.3 is ok!!

[image]

Comment: you can do it by css!!

Comment: i know, but i cant find where!!!

Comment: are you using theme?

Comment: yes i am using a theme

Comment: share link if you cant change by yourself

Comment: i have changed my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78628/discussion-between-ketan-and-maartenv1).

Comment: I am in the chat

Comment: Give me url of your store

Comment: In chat please, i am there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to file and update css in this class

> app\design\frontend\Ubertheme\sportsgear\web\css\styles-m.css

```
.price-container .price-including-tax + .price-excluding-tax, .price-container .weee, .price-container .price-including-tax + .price-excluding-tax .price, .price-container .weee .price, .price-container .weee + .price-excluding-tax::before, .price-container .weee + .price-excluding-tax .price {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

run command for deploy

Comment: Im sorry there is no file styles-m.css in that map

Comment: It's base css. create there file there and add content view-source:http://shop.targetcars.eu/pub/static/version1528201741/frontend/Ubertheme/sportsgear/en_GB/css/styles-m.css

Comment: then update css as i have show in answer.So,in future when you update it will not ovveride